# Creating enemy with vision radius and blind spots

Tags: flutter, flame, bonfire

I’m using flutter and flame to create a game similar to sneak ops. I’m wondering how to go about creating an enemy that has a vision radius or area, that is obstructed by objects.
[image]

Comment: http://www.roguebasin.com/index.php?title=Field_of_Vision lists a bunch of fov algorithms for tile-based games.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built into Flame for this currently, but in the next version we'll have raycasting that can be used for this.